# Title for a proposition. What am I doing incorrectly

Tags: theorems

I defined the proposition object in the exact same way as the theorem object:

```
\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
```

But when I give a name to a Theorem object:

```
\begin{theorem}[Theorem of Webber]
\end{theorem}
```

I would as wished:

Theorem 1. (Theorem of Webber).

But when I do the exact same for a proposition, I get an untidy looking

Proposition 1. *[Proposition of Sebastian]*

Why is this happening? How can I circumvent it?

Edit:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Theorem of Webber]
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition of Sebastian]
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which package do you use for theorems? Please post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the problem.

Comment: package amsmath

Comment: `amsmath` has nothing to do with theorems,  Perhaps you mean `amsthm`,  In any event, we need to know what document class you are using, and what other packages may be involved.  Please add a small, compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that produces the problem you describe, so that potential helpers will have something concrete to experiment with,

Comment: @barbarabeeton done

Comment: This can be reproduced if there is something invisible before the `[` in the proposition. Check for the presence of some invisible character.

Comment: If an invisible character exists, it should be noted in the log with a message such as "character does not exist in ... font".

Comment: Worked, thanks!+